# Geocoding with Python - Get the adress from just the company name

Tags: python, web-scraping, geocoding

I'm currently working on a project in which I have a list of company names and I have to get the address of each one of them. I’ve tried with geocoding google API or even the following code but it doesn’t work.

```
> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
> geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
> location = geolocator.geocode("Company name")
> print(location.address) 
> print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
> print(location.raw)
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

I selected a fast food place at random called Chilango in Angel, Islington, UK. I then tried the  [Open Search (Nominatim) API](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/open/nominatim-search/search/) via MapQuest. Free and requires API key.

I mimicked one of the example GET requests:

```
import requests

res = requests.get('http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?key=myKey&format=json&q=Chilango+[fast food]&addressdetails=1&limit=3&viewbox=-1.99%2C52.02%2C0.78%2C50.94&exclude_place_ids=41697').json()
```

From the documentation:

> Enclosing the query string in [] causes Nominatim to do a facility
>   search. For example, q=[pub] returns results where type=pub in
>   OpenStreetMap.

The desired result was number 2 out of the 3 results I limited the search results to.

Answer (score 0):

First, reproduce the error:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
location = geolocator.geocode("Company name")
```

that gives the error message:

> GeocoderServiceError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:852)

This is a known issue and I found a solution here: https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/124

```
import certifi
import ssl
import geopy.geocoders

ctx = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where()) 
geopy.geocoders.options.default_ssl_context = ctx                                                       

geolocator = geopy.geocoders.Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
location = geolocator.geocode("Lozari beach corse")
```

Now it works

```
print(location)                                                                                                                          
# Out: Plage de Lozari, T 30, Palasca, Calvi, Haute-Corse, Corse, France métropolitaine, 20226, France
```